# The destination pkcs12 keystore has different storepass and keypass. Please retry with -destkeypass specified

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, jwt, keystore

I'm new to the key generation. When I follow up on the steps I get an error as below...

```
D:\My_Personal_Projects\springblog>keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore springblog.jks -destkeystore springblog.jks -deststoretype pkcs12"
Enter source keystore password:
Enter key password for <springblog>
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: The destination pkcs12 keystore has different storepass and keypass. Please retry with -destkeypass specified.
```

Following are the steps I went through

```
D:\My_Personal_Projects\springblogfrontend>cd springblogfrontend

D:\My_Personal_Projects\springblogfrontend\springblogfrontend>keytool -genkey -alias springblog -keyalg RSA --keystore springblog.jks 
-keysize 2048
Enter keystore password:  
Re-enter new password: 
What is your first and last name?
  [Unknown]:  Niroshan
What is the name of your organizational unit?
  [Unknown]:  springblog
What is the name of your organization?
  [Unknown]:
What is the name of your City or Locality?
  [Unknown]:
What is the name of your State or Province?
  [Unknown]:
What is the two-letter country code for this unit?
  [Unknown]:  

Is CN=Niroshan, OU=springblog, O=Unknown, L=Unknown, ST=Unknown, C=Unknown correct?
  [no]:  yes

Enter key password for <springblog>
        (RETURN if same as keystore password):
Re-enter new password:

Warning:
The JKS keystore uses a proprietary format. It is recommended to migrate to PKCS12 which is an industry standard format using "keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore springblog.jks -destkeystore springblog.jks -deststoretype pkcs12".

D:\My_Personal_Projects\springblogfrontend\springblogfrontend>keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore springblog.jks -destkeystore springblog.jks -deststoretype pkcs12
Enter source keystore password:
Enter key password for <springblog>
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: The destination pkcs12 keystore has different storepass and keypass. Please retry with -destkeypass specified.
```

What makes this error? Any help is really appreciated

Comment: Why are you naming a PKCXS#12 keystore as `*.jks`? Don't do that.

Comment: @user207421: obviously because the keytool warning (in 8usomething and 9.0.1 up) says to, although I concur it's not a good idea. OP: wjhich Java are you using? AFAIK only j8 both creates jks by default and gives the warning, but in the versions I have `-importkeystore` prompts for the destination store password, twice, _before_ the source password(s).

Comment: I am actually pretty new to this. This is my first key generation. Can I know the idea behind this key generation   user207421 dave_thompson_085? I still didn't figure out the solution either.

Answer (score 3):

This error occurs because in your keystore are two different passwords. First one is a keystore password (or *storepass*), look at these lines:

```
Enter keystore password:
Re-enter new password:
```

Second one is a key password for your alias (or *keypass*), keytool asks for this password in the end of keystore generation, look at these lines:

```
Enter key password for <springblog>
        (RETURN if same as keystore password):
Re-enter new password:
```

Here are two options to solve the problem with the keytool error:

1. When keytool asks for keypass, just press RETURN as suggested, and then `keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore springblog.jks -destkeystore springblog.jks -deststoretype pkcs12` will work as intended, without any errors.
2. Add `-destkeypass` option with your keypass (password for alias) when you are doing above mentioned migrate/import command. In this case keytool gives you warning `Warning:  Different store and key passwords not supported for PKCS12 KeyStores. Ignoring user-specified -destkeypass value.`, but import will be finished succesfully.